# android change default color of selector and tab underline

Tags: java, android, listview, tabs, themes

How to change (using theme modifications) the default color of selector (ListView, GridView) and Tab selector/underline color. 
I use actionbarsherlock and Theme.Sherlock as main application theme.

Below are the pictures describing what do I want to change.

Thanks

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to style your action bar you will need to style its parts individually - there is no color attribute that would change the light blue color to something else.

Basically what you need to do is override styles and change some of the attributes and add some new drawables. If your action bar includes spinners, dropdown panels, radio buttons etc. you'll also need to provide new colored images for those. I recommend that you check the ActionBarSherlock `styled` sample (which you downloaded with the library), particularly its `styles.xml`.